# Arranging Google Form Responses into an already existing Spreadsheet Database

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

**Background**

I am making a Database of organiser names, which i want to update with a Google Form.
I already made a Form which feeds a Spreadsheet "Form Responses" sheet with the organiser details: Continent, Country and Chapter/City. The Database is already existing with current organisers, split into continent specific sheets, so i need to add new organisers from the form to this database. If a new organiser is from a new country/chapter, that needs to be added to the database as well.

**Question**

What formula can I use to feed the "Form Responses" sheet rows into the "Database" sheets, without having multiple rows of the same Country and Chapter? That is, add the "Organiser" column to an existing "Country" + "Chapter", or add the new "Country" + "Chapter" + "Organiser" to the bottom of the correct "Continent_Database".

Maybe the only way to do this might be to add all new rows from the "Form Responses" sheet to the bottom of the correct "Continent_Database", and merge the rows in the case of already existing Country + Chapter, in an additional sheet.

**Example**

Spreadsheet example with some test Form Responses and a "Africa_Database" example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QaDNQp-HrbueQchmlXGSr7cFZ9r2x7ml148vSJL4Q0w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You could be looking to use a query here. In the case below 'A2' points a cell containing a country name. Transpose will convert a downward list to a horizontal and the query will get all names from column G where column C contains that the country in cell 'A2'

```
=transpose(QUERY('Form Respones'!B:G,"SELECT G WHERE C ='"&A2&"'",0))
```

Here is an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o2-pDh42EmVfzmzKZVJXxLU6sfCMXFBkXr4yyN3Rix8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your formula put me in the right direction, but did not give me a solution to my problem. It also looks like you altered the Form Responses sheet in your example. 
Do you know if it is possible to put the transposed query inside ARRAYFORMULA(). I tried, but it only works for the top row.

Comment: ARRAYFORMULA() doesn't support a query. Perhaps this might help shed some light: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97314